# Renaming multiple files in a folder by adding Prefix using python

Tags: python

```
Python script.

import os
[os.rename(f, f.replace('', 'xyz_')) for f in os.listdir('.') 
if not f.startswith('.')]
```

from above script i want to rename the files as
Before

```
1.0.1.0.html
1.20.0.0.html
1.11.1.0.html
1.10.1.0.html
```

after renaming,

```
xyz_1.0.1.0.html
xyz_1.20.0.0.html
xyz_1.11.1.0.html
xyz_1.10.1.0.html
```

Is it possible,can anyone help me out.

Comment: `os.rename(f, 'xyz_' + f)` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use glob to find all the html files:

```
from glob import glob
import os
pre = "xyz_"
[os.rename(f, "{}{}".format(pre, f)) for f in glob("*.html")]
```

html files starting with a `.` should be ignored as *[glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) treats filenames beginning with a dot (.) as special cases.*.

```
def glob(pathname):
    """Return a list of paths matching a pathname pattern.

    The pattern may contain simple shell-style wildcards a la
    fnmatch. However, unlike fnmatch, filenames starting with a
    dot are special cases that are not matched by '*' and '?'
    patterns.

    """
    return list(iglob(pathname))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
import os
[os.rename(f, 'xyz_' + str(f)) for f in os.listdir('.') 
if ((not f.startswith('.')) and f.endswith(".html"))]
```

Comment: it is replacing also with other extensions, but i want only .html files should be replaced

Comment: Edited to include that.

Comment: Thanks Buddy

But if i want to replace any text with new filename,in this there is not a option, as in my code,there is find what option and replace with is .

can you add this option in it please.

for example.

"xyz_1.0.2.html" rename as "abc_1.0.2.html"